# Mapping a keras NN over data lists in R

Tags: r, purrr, furrr

I am trying to figure out the correct method of going about applying a keras model to each of my lists. I have used the `iris` dataset and created 4 lists and the goal is to correctly predict `versicolor` or `virginica` (I omit `setosa` because I want a binary classification model).

```
data(iris)
iris <- iris %>% 
  mutate(
    splt = sample(4, size = nrow(.), replace = TRUE),
    binary = case_when(
      Species == "versicolor" ~ 0,
      Species == "virginica" ~ 1
    )
  ) %>%  
  filter(Species != "setosa") %>% 
  split(., .$splt)

iris_x_train <- iris %>% 
  map(., ~select(., Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width) %>% 
        as.matrix())

iris_y_train <- iris %>% 
  map(., ~select(., binary) %>% 
        to_categorical(2))

NN_model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 4, activation = 'relu', input_shape = 4) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 2, activation = 'softmax')

NN_model %>% 
  summary

NN_model %>% 
  compile(
    loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer_sgd(lr = 0.01, momentum = 0.9),
    metrics = c('accuracy')
  )
```

My problem occurs here. When I apply the below code:

```
NN_model %>%
  future_map(., ~future_map2(
    .x = iris_x_train,
    .y = iris_y_train,
    ~fit(
      x = .x,
      y = .y,
      epochs = 5,
      batch_size = 20,
      validation_split = 0
    )
  )
  )
```

I get this error:

> Error in py_get_item_impl(x, key, FALSE) :    TypeError: 'Sequential'
>   object does not support indexing

When I apply this code:

```
NN_model %>%
  future_map2(
    .x = iris_x_train,
    .y = iris_y_train,
    ~fit(
      x = .x,
      y = .y,
      epochs = 5,
      batch_size = 20,
      validation_split = 0
      )
    )
```

I get this error:

> ~fit(x = .x, y = .y, epochs = 5, batch_size = 20, validation_split =
>   0)  Error in py_call_impl(callable,
>   dots$args, dots$keywords) :    Evaluation error: Unable to convert R
>   object to Python type.

How can I map a keras model to each of the 4 datasets?

```
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)
library(furrr)
library(purrr)
```

The following works for the first list:

```
NN_model %>% 
  fit(
    x = iris_x_train[[1]],
    y = iris_y_train[[1]],
    epochs = 50,
    batch_size = 20,
    validation_split = 0
  )
```

**EDIT:** I seem to have solved it.

Putting the `NN_model` inside the `fit()` function appears to work.

```
future_map2(
    .x = iris_x_train,
    .y = iris_y_train,
    ~fit(NN_model,
      .x,
      .y,
      epochs = 5,
      batch_size = 20,
      validation_split = 0
    )
  )
```